# Laravel blade checkbox is always invalidated

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 9. When I check a checkbox and save it, I always get the error `The calculator field must be true or false.`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('save', function(Request $request) {
  $request->validate([
    'calculator' => 'required|boolean'
  ]);
  return redirect('/');
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    @if($errors->any())
    <div class='alert alert-danger rounded-0 mb-0'>
        {!! implode('<hr />', $errors->all(':message')) !!}
    </div>
    @endif

    <form method="post" action="save">
        @csrf
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="calculator" id="calculator" />
            <label for="calculator">Calculator</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please debug the $request->calculator value? just add dd($request->calculator); before validation codes

Comment: "on" for checked, "null" for unchecked.

Comment: that's the point, the checkbox has value "on" if it's checked,

Answer (score 0):

That's because Laravel sends checkbox value as `on`

You can see that if you dump your request:

```
dd($request->input());
```

In order to bypass that, you can add a value to your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="1" name="calculator" id="calculator" />
```

This way, Laravel will now send `1` as your input, and you will be able to validate it with `boolean` rule.

Also, you can use a different approach. Laravel provides [accepted](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-accepted) rule as well:

> The field under validation must be yes, on, 1, or true. This is useful for validating "Terms of Service" acceptance.

So in this case, you would just change your validation rule:

```
$request->validate([
    'calculator' => 'required|accepted'
  ]);
```

Comment: But if I uncheck, I get a validation error "The calculator field must be accepted".

Comment: Is that checkbox always required?

Comment: Well the user can toggle it.

Comment: Seeing your initial request validation, it seemed like that field is always required ```'calculator' => 'required``` . Then you can use the first approach, and just remove ```required``` from the validation